# Instant Run AndroidStudio 2.0 Beta 6 doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying to enable 'Instant Run' feature for my project but it's no too easy as it seemed initially. I've ended up with constant

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.package.MyApplication
```

I've tried switching to legacy multidexing, tried switching instant run off and then switching it back on, tried to switch off multidexing at all on brand new project with just one activity. All attempts were headed by project cleaning.

Over and over again it fails with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Don't understand how it works for others.

P.S.

Already looked into

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199327
- http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build

Answer (score 0):

I installed the beta and just enabled Instant Run in Android Studio > Settings > search for Instant Run if you haven't.

Class not found exception is another problem.

`com.my.package.MyApplication`
is this the real package you are using?

Comment: Package name is from simple test app, in app I develop it's different. Instant Run is enabled. Actually, if to disable it building works fine but takes ~5min on my real one.

Comment: oh, it's actually com.mypackage.MyApplication. So, syntax wise all correct.

Comment: So you updated Android Studio to  2.0 Beta 6, then your gradle plugin as well, Instant Run is enabled and still no success? Try Invalidate Caches/Restart, still can't build?

Comment: Yep, all as you say. Tried invalidate caches/restart and problem still there :( Do you use Mac or some other platform? I'm on Windows 8.1 maybe culprit is in that. .

Comment: Hmm sorry I couldn't help then, let's wait for another suggestion. I'm Ivan too btw haha, and I am using Windows 10. It runs fine.

Comment: No worries, namesake :) I just came to my colleague who uses Mac-Book and this feature works perfectly good for him. So, I prone to blame Window 8. Will check it at home with Windows 10 and report here.